# Устойчивая к декомпиляции DLL (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dll

Скажите, есть ли сегодня механизмы написания DLL на Delphi, которую невозможно было бы декомпилировать - если да, то дайте пожалуйста информацию или какие-то правильные ссылки на информацию, на какой версии Delphi и как это можно сделать?

Comment: Возможно, вы имели ввиду устойчивость к взлому? Потому что на любой версии Delphi привести исполняемый код к исходному виду pas-файлов не получится, если отключить отладочную информацию. Компилятор Delphi создает нативный, а не интерпретируемый код, так что можно считать что компиляция - это "путь в один конец"

Comment: Декомпилировать в исходный код невозможно будет dll, созданную в любой версии Delphi (если не включать в неё отладочную информацию, как сказали выше). Однако декомпилировать в псевдо-код или в ассемблер - можно любое приложение. И защиты от этого не существует, иначе приложение не сможет выполняться. Однако можно затруднить взлом, но это решается усложнением алгоритма работы приложения и слабо зависит от среды разработки. Ещё есть такая вещь как полиморфный код, который изменяет сам себя в процессе выполнения, но это с вероятностью 99% заставит делать стойку на ваше приложение все антивирусы.

Comment: Я делаю DLL, с которой будет работать коммерческая обработка 1С, конечно же смысл данной DLL в том, чтобы она выполняла часть сложного функционала, а так-же проверяла лицензии на неком веб-ресурсе. Т.е.коммерческая обработка 1С будет использовать методы из DLL. И вот нужно защититься от того, чтобы не могли вскрыть алгоритм того функционала, который делает DLL.

Comment: Ну тут можно попробовать шифровать код, как делают, например, всякие asprotect (AFAIR) и защиты на игрушках. Но при наличии желания, времени и средств вскрыть возможно любую защиту, поэтому весь вопрос в балансе - стоимость приложения/трудозатраты на взлом.

Comment: Понятно, большое спасибо! Я пишу сейчас эту DLL на Delphi 7 - я смоту шифровать код на нем? (я просто еще не знаю как шифровать код)))

Comment: Раз вы не знаете, как защитить ваше приложение - лучше не пытаться изобрести велосипед, в противном случае очень велика вероятность того, что у вас будет навешана куча проверок, но все они легко нивелируются всего одной заменой jz на jnz (к примеру). Возьмите готовое решение - ASProtect, VMProtect  и т.п. Это будет гораздо правильнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В дополнение к сказаномому @Alekcvp и @cpp_user могу вот, что добавить:

**Вариант №1.**

Вырезаем всю отладочную инфу и компилим в релиз версии. В добавок вырезаем весь rtti. Это делает ваш код относительно "чистым". Ну тут есть не большие "огрешности":

- Компилятор все равно вставит rtti от стадартных библеотек. Это можно вылечить перекомпилацией rtl, но это сложно.
- В коде могут использоваться такие процедуры как SetLength/New/Dispose и тд. Всем им нужен rtti типа передаваемой переменой, то есть rtti для таких переменых будет в бинарнике.
- Сами классы внутри бинарников имеют некую информацию без rtti, такие как имя класса, список полей(без имен) для авто освобождения.

*Какие плюсы:*

- Бесплатно
- Отсеивает совсем линивых

*Какие минусы:*

- Разбирающейся хоть немного спец разберет бинарник без всяких проблем

**Вариант №2**

Берем другой язык. Например С++ или подобный. Мало чем отличается от предыдущего в плане взлома но, инфы в бинарнике как правило на порядок меньше, поумолчанию.

*Какие плюсы:*

- Бесплатно
- За счет всяких оптимизации С++ может не много усложнить процесс разбора бинарника в сравнении с предыдущим вариантом.

*Какие минусы:*

- Профессионал разберется без проблем
- Сложнее писать код для С++ (язык сложнее)

**Вариант №3**

Берем стороние средства защиты. Тут нужно выбирать средства, которые реализуют защиту посредством виртуальной машины в ядре операционки. Всё остальные(шифраторы или упаковщики) ломаются очень лекго.
    Это пожалуй самый надежный метод если защита строится локально. Но тут нужно понимать, что такое решение для всего своего кода может очень сильно снизить производительность.

*Какие плюсы:*

- Для взлома понадобится очень не плохой спец и это спецу понадобится
  возможно много времени, а это много денег и есть шанс, что ломать
  изза этого не станут.

*Какие минусы:*

- Стоит денег(может даже не мальньких).
- Если виртуалка была взломана(и особенно метод взлома лежит в
  интернэтах) все пиши пропало.

**Вариант №4**

Можно постараться реализовать секретную логику на своем сервере. Тут правда нужен свой сервер и если клиентов много, то нужен мощный сервер.

*Какие плюсы:*

- Локальный взлом бесполезен, а чтоб пролезть на сервак нужен
  хороший(дорогой) спец.

*Какие минусы:*

- Стоит денег(при большой кол-во клиентов стоит бешеных денег).

Comment: Не холивара ради, а именно в целях повышения образованности: можно какой-нибудь пруфлинк, где разжевывается, что компиляторы C++ генерируют более оптимальный машинный код, чем компилятор Delphi "за счет всяческих оптимизаций"? "Меня терзают смутные сомнения" :)

Comment: Тема оптимизации большая. И это отдельный вопрос)). Если вкратце, то оптимизатор в Delphi нормально отимизирует, только в пределах одной процедуры(но он не способен на раскрутку циклов например)

Answer (score 0):

Все можно декомпилировать, но можно запутать код (сгенерировать кучу бесполезного сена в которой имеет смысл маленькая иголка) или часть кода виртуализировать в байт код который будет выполнятся виртуальной машиной.

Comment: А есть какая-то может книга умная, как делаются такие вещи, или где-то можно почитать про то, как это делается?

Comment: Первое делается кодогенерацией. Второе скользкая дорожка потому что антивирусы будут ругаться